# Load very big csv file into table with pagination using just JQuery and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, csv, jquery-pagination

I have trying to load one .csv file into a table using JQuery. Because the .csv file is very big I'm trying to load into a table using pagination.
This is the .csv file named **nums.csv**:

> It has over 350.000 rows so I pasted here only a few of them to get an
> idea.

```
Day,Hour,N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9,N10,N11,N12,N13,N14,N15,N16,N17,N18,N19,N20
1996-03-18,15:00,4,9,10,16,21,22,23,26,27,34,35,41,42,48,62,66,68,73,76,78
1996-03-19,15:00,6,12,15,19,28,33,35,39,44,48,49,59,62,63,64,67,69,71,75,77
1996-03-21,15:00,2,4,6,7,15,16,17,19,20,26,28,45,48,52,54,69,72,73,75,77
1996-03-22,15:00,3,8,15,17,19,25,30,33,34,35,36,38,44,49,60,61,64,67,68,75
1996-03-25,15:00,2,10,11,14,18,22,26,27,29,30,42,44,45,55,60,61,66,67,75,79
1996-03-26,15:00,4,10,12,19,20,22,30,31,32,37,44,45,55,57,60,61,64,69,70,72
1996-03-28,15:00,1,4,9,11,12,13,15,26,32,35,39,40,49,53,62,63,72,73,77,78
1996-03-29,15:00,3,9,13,14,24,27,29,32,35,41,44,47,49,50,61,64,66,69,72,73
1996-04-01,15:00,2,4,6,9,12,14,20,21,25,35,39,43,44,45,48,50,52,61,69,72
1996-04-02,15:00,4,6,9,11,13,21,23,32,33,35,41,43,51,57,63,66,67,70,75,78
1996-04-04,15:00,8,10,11,12,13,18,21,26,31,32,40,44,48,49,53,61,65,70,75,80
1996-04-05,15:00,12,14,15,17,23,28,35,41,46,49,50,51,53,58,64,66,72,74,79,80
1996-04-09,15:00,7,10,13,21,26,30,36,41,43,46,53,59,60,61,62,64,65,74,77,79
1996-04-11,15:00,1,3,13,16,18,23,24,25,31,37,38,41,42,47,49,63,67,73,74,76
1996-04-12,15:00,2,4,10,19,20,21,22,24,30,33,35,37,45,47,58,59,64,68,76,77
1996-04-15,15:00,2,10,14,16,25,27,28,29,30,31,32,41,43,45,49,60,61,62,69,71
1996-04-16,15:00,3,5,6,12,17,21,22,23,30,33,34,39,41,42,56,65,67,73,76,80
1996-04-18,15:00,6,8,22,27,28,30,36,37,42,45,46,56,57,58,59,65,69,71,75,77
1996-04-19,15:00,8,9,10,11,13,15,23,24,26,31,32,33,42,47,54,57,62,64,78,79
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>CSV File to HTML Table Using AJAX jQuery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/tst.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="error_message" style="display:none">
        <br>
        <br>
        <p align="center">The following errors occurred:</p>
        <br>
        <p id="xhr" align="center"></p>
        <p id="msg" align="center"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <h1 align="center">CSV File to HTML Table Using AJAX jQuery</h1>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div id="draws_table"></div>
            <div class="skeptik-paging"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**tst.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "nums.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            var numPerPage = 10;
            var employee_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
            var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
            table_data += '<tr>';
            var headers = employee_data[0].split(",");
            for (var cell_count = 0; cell_count < headers.length; cell_count++) {
                table_data += '<th>' + headers[cell_count] + '</th>';
            }
            table_data += '</tr>';

            
            for (var i = 0; i * numPerPage < employee_data.length; i += 1) {
                var dataPage = employee_data.slice(i * numPerPage, i * numPerPage + numPerPage);
                for(var bulk = 0; bulk<dataPage.length; bulk++){
                    for( var row =0; row<bulk.length; row++){
                        var cell_data = row.split(",");
                        for (var cell_count = 0; cell_count < cell_data.length; cell_count++) {
                            table_data += '<td>' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</td>';
                        }
                        table_data += '</tr>';
                    }
                }
                //end of each function
                $(this).find(".skeptik-paging").append("<span>" + (i + 1) + "</span>");
            }

            table_data += '</table>';
            $('#draws_table').html(table_data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            document.getElementById("error_message").style.display = "block"
            $("p#xhr").text(xhr.status);
            $("p#msg").text(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

I have found two code samples [here](https://codepen.io/bombcat/pen/eYpvPX) and [here](https://codepen.io/rorofat/pen/WpmobL) but they do not use a csv file to load into a table they just show some pagination sample for the tables and they get the data not from the .csv file but from html code using .find method. I tried somehow to adapt and also to modify my code but in vain.

As I can see the header of the table is displayed well but for some reason it doesn't show the data with pagination into table. I'm posting this here for help and I think it will help many others since there isn't something like that here but many people is looking for a solution. I know there are some API to be used but I need just JQuery/JavaScript.

Thank you in advance!

P.S. I want to be able to add custom css styles that is why I added th and tr tags in the code.

Comment: 350,000 rows is far too much data for the browser UI to be able to handle effectively. Do you have any other way to provide the data to the browser so that it could be paged, or filtered? For example, querying a server-side database would be a *far* better approach.

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan mentioned 350k row on one shoot, will make the page crash, and the UI Freeze.

Comment: @Mina What if it loads and display first page which means let's say the first 100 rows and after that it continues to run in the background and load the rest of the data on the next other pages? This in fact what I am trying to do. How to do it, please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I want to load first 100 rows and display them on the first page of the table and after that continue to run in the background and populate the next pages to end. How to do that please? Thank you very much!

Comment: You can't partially load content from a CSV file over Ajax. It's all or nothing. This is why a database is the only workable solution for that amount of data

Comment: I have changed my mind and I want to load another .csv file which is much smaller (~300 rows) with this code I posted above but it's not loading at all. It display only header but no table page. Could you help me with this please? Thank you so much in advance! P.S. The code is exactly the same as the one above.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Also the .csv file has the same format and the same name. Thank you again!